# TYPO3 RTE link/a-tag add data-attribute

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, rte

I would like that in RTE (TYPO3 v7.6), when you add a link, you can add data attributes to the a-tag using a select field.

Is that possible, if so, what should I do? I don't find a start.

Answer (score 1):

In TYPO3 8.7 a LinkHandler API was added which should (sorry, I didn't try that yet) allow to add that to e.g. `TCEMAIN.linkHandler.url`. (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/8.7/en-us/ApiOverview/LinkBrowser/Linkhandler/Index.html)

Earlier it looks pretty hardcoded: https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_7-6/typo3/sysext/recordlist/Classes/LinkHandler/UrlLinkHandler.php#L89

You could use XClass'ing but it might be more efficient to switch to another TYPO3 version.